# Negative binomial with conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let X be a random variable that follows a negative binomial distribution: NB(r=4, p=0.4)
Calculate P(X = 8 | x > 6)

I know how to calculate P(X = 8):

$$
\binom{7}{3} \cdot (1 - 0.4)^{7-3} \cdot (0.4)^{4} = 0.1161
$$

And this is what I wrote for P(X > 6), tough I'm not so sure about it:

$$
1 - P(X \lt 6) = 1 - \big[ P(X = 4) + P(X = 5) \big] 
$$

But after that I'm stuck. I don't understand how to solve P(X = 8) when there is (P > 6) as a conditional probability.

Thanks!

Comment: You want $\Pr(X\gt 6)=1-\Pr(X\le 6)$. So one more term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the definition.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=8\mid X>6)
 &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=8 \cap X>6)}{\mathsf P(X>6)}
\\[1ex]
 &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=8)}{\mathsf P(X>6)}
\end{align}$

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd step, where did the (X > 6) in the numerator go?

Comment: @Emilie $(X=8 \cap X>6) \iff (X=8)$  The value of X which is both equal to 8 and greater than 6, is 8.